# Arrange user controls dynamically on parent form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, user-controls

How can I arrange controls in my parent form by **code**?

So far I call the user controls with this code;

```
 Me.ParentForm.Controls.Remove(Me)
 controlMain()
```

I want the **user controls** arrange itself whenever the user resize the parent form or maximize the form. Currently, I set the controls by,

```
    Public Sub controlMain()
        Dim usrctl As New _ctlMain
        _Main.Controls.Add(usrctl)
        usrctl.Location = New Point(_Main.Width / 2 - usrctl.Width / 2, _Main.Height / 2 -usrctl.Height / 2)
    End Sub
```

which is on a module. **_Main** is my parent form while **_ctlMain** is the control being called. I do not intend to put the user control on the parent form during design because I have other user controls to call after a specific function in an active control is called.
I have tried the **autosize** property of usercontrol but I guess it doesn't work on my application. Usercontrol doesn't have the dock and anchor properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the automatic layout controls, like a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) or a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

Instead of adding your user controls to the form itself, add them to either a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel control that has been placed on top of the form using `DockStyle.Fill`.

It sounds to me like a FlowLayoutPanel is what you want. With that, the layout of the controls is handled entirely automatically, and they are positioned either in left-to-right or top-to-bottom order, depending on the value of the [`FlowDirection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection.aspx).

The only reason to choose a TableLayoutPanel is if you need to have more precise control over the exact positioning of the controls. It works just like an HTML table, with each control getting its own "cell".

You can also set the `Dock` and/or `Fill` properties of the individual user controls if you'd like to ensure that their sizes are automatically adjusted. For example, you can set each control to fill the entire cell in which it is placed in a TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: I never thought that I can add usercontrols to flowlayoutpanel. I'll try that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, here's what I did;

            Dim usrctl As New _ctlMain
        _Main.FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(usrctl)
        usrctl.Location = New Point(_Main.FlowLayoutPanel.Width / 2 - usrctl.Width / 2, _Main.FlowLayoutPanel.Height / 2 - usrctl.Height / 2)

Comment: Tried to set the FlowDirection to either LeftToRight/RightToLeft and all I get is the usercontrol moved to the other side of the screen. I'm expecting it to be on the center of the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: And there is no **Dock** and **Fill** on user control.

Comment: There's no centering option for the FlowLayoutPanel. You'll need to use a TableLayoutPanel for that. And yes, all user controls have `Dock` and `Fill` properties; they inherit those from the `Control` base class.

Comment: I meant the `UserControl` not the individual toolbox controls. There is no way to set `Dock` and `Fill` properties on design time, unless you drag the `UserControl` inside the `Form`. I guess I will just create individual forms and drag the `UserControl` inside to use the `Dock` and `Fill` properties. Thank you.