# c# Smooth Switching from Form to Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I have an application which has around 9 forms.
Whenever I click the "Next button" on one form to open the next, the next form doesn't open instantly. Instead for a split second or two the desktop is shown and then the new form.

So something like this is happening:

1 form->desktop-> another form

Why is this happening?

How do I fix it?

It's making my application look bad and is not giving it the feel of a desktop application.

All my forms open in Maximum state and have no borders. It has a somewhat Metro UI.

Comment: send your code for check what is problem

Comment: are you doing a time consuming task in your forms constructor?

Comment: No. My constructor is Just InitializeComponent()

My form Load event has few tasks

Comment: Does it have to do with RAM of computer?

Comment: Why not make a proper wizard instead of individual forms?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Wizards have a **Next** button. Is your app essentially a wizard/procedure/workflow?  If so, then make one form but use pages instead.

Comment: No. 
I cannot re-build my app now. It has lots of lines of code

Comment: Are you hiding the 1st form when you open the 2nd..forms?

Comment: Yes.
new Form1().Show();
this.Hide();

Answer (score 0):

If you really intend to have multiple forms instead of having multiple user controls arranged properly in pages (which I definitely recommend you to do!), then you should initialize the forms before showing them.
Essentially, you should cache these forms, by initializing all of them before you show the first form.
You should then be able to switch quite quickly by doing what you're already doing:

```
form1.Hide();
form2.Show();
```

It's really ugly, but it gets you there. If that is still too slow, you should simply change the design of your application.

Comment: How do I have multiple User Controls arranged properly in frames?

Comment: There are plenty of ways. For example, this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920389/arrange-user-controls-dynamically-on-parent-form-in-vb-net. FlowLayoutPanels or TableLayoutPanels are widely used. You could also have a SplitContainer or a TabControl. It really depends on your requirements.